# Como pegar o valor de um objeto a partir do seu endereço de memória?

Tags: python, memória

Segundo a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id), a função `id` - pelo menos no CPython (implementação padrão da linguagem) - retorna o endereço de memória de um objeto. Por exemplo:

```
x = 5
print(hex(id(x)) # 0x0123
```

Tem como fazer o oposto: obter valor `5` a partir do endereço de memória?

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Qual seria a utilidade prática disso?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer isso usando [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html)

```
import ctypes
a = 10
ctypes.cast(id(a), ctypes.py_object).value
#10
```

Traduzido do SO Inglês deste [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47269001/getting-python-variable-name-or-value-from-memory-location)